# HTML Radio button table need to build it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I was doing some re factoring for a page, In that page I have bunch of radio buttons group.Data for the radio buttons comes from database and sometimes from cache layer.

I will probably be having close to 100 radio buttons. I need to arrange them in 5 column 20 rows.

Data population happens via arraylist. I was thinking for converting this arraylist into json and then using it to lay out the radio buttons in the HTML table format.

I know there are many plugins out there for building tables,however they are not meeting my requirements.How do I built 5 rows 10 column table with my data on the fly.

Something like

```
<tr>
<td>radio1</td>
<td>radio2</td>


<td>radio10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>radio11</td>
<td>radio12</td>

<td>radio20</td>
```

The caveat here is that I do not know in advance as how much data I m going to get for the table.
Appreciate some thoughts.

Comment: Simple is looping through your JSON array and building HTML through the jQuery functions, like append("some html here"). Or you can look into jQuery templates.

Comment: Don't I need to count the items in the array.For example first 10 items should be in first row, second 10 items should be second row like wise.

Comment: @KiranBadi take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scnu5o4y/). Maybe it will give you a clue how it can be done.

Comment: @KiranBadi and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scnu5o4y/1/) with one-dimension array.

Comment: I have data something like var data = ['radio1','radio2'... 'radio100']. So pronbably some maths is required here I think

Comment: Can we make this rowcount dynamic rather than fixing it to some value.var rowElementsCount = 3;

Comment: You should fix either columns or rows count. Otherwise, how can we understand  how many elements per row we need?

Comment: I think Regent your fiddle works. I can get the count and then build the table now.Thanks for suggestion. I own you and DvS a beer.

Comment: Columns count is fixed to 5.

Comment: In your question there are 10 columns :) What I want to say is that you can use one-dimension array with constant for columns (or rows) count, or you can use two-dimension array.

Comment: I never knew Jquery also provides templates. Just googled it and found it awesome. Thanks DvS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop through your JSON object.
2. Use mod ('%') to append a new tr every ten items
3. Output td items (with content) to the last tr added.

If you're using jQuery, try something like this:

```
var holderDiv = $('#myDivId');
var i = 0;
var myData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
$.each(myData, function(key,value) {
  if(i == 0 || i == i%10){
    holderDiv.append('<tr>');
  }
  holderDiv.find('tr:last-child').append('<td>' + value + '</td>');
  i++;
}
```

Comment: In your answer variable `i` is always equaled to `0`, you know... Also  `find('tr:last-child')` is incorrect (and redundant, by the way).